# What's the purpose of `qt_noop`

Tags: c++, qt, no-op

I just found the existence of `qt_noop()` define in the qglobal.h as:

```
inline void qt_noop() {}
```

What's the point of it?

Comment: *noop* -- *no op* -- No operation.

Comment: Precisely! Why give a damn creating a function that does... nothing!

Comment: I get a linking error when building Qt Creator against a Qt static compilation in qt_noop function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "`noop`" name is short for "no operation", meaning it is a place-holder function that does nothing.

You may also know `NOP`, which exists in assembly-language.

I know it's used internally in some macros that should do something only for debug builds, for example:

```
#  ifndef QT_NO_DEBUG
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((!(cond)) ? qt_assert(#cond,__FILE__,__LINE__) : qt_noop())
#  else
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) qt_noop()
#  endif
#endif
```

Comment: So its sole purpose is to use the ternary operator (why not a single if?) since it could be omitted in the 2nd define?

Comment: It can't be omitted in 2nd define. The Q_ASSERT macro is usually used like normal function call, i.e. `Q_ASSERT(xxx == yyy);`. So the macro must expand to code that can be followed with semicolon without any errors/warnings. As for the "single if", there are some issues with macros containing if when they are used inside other if statements without braces (see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.4), so ternary operator might be a better idea here.

Comment: Accepted more for the comment and the link than the answer... anyway, thanks! :)